# How to know what destroys a Codeigniter session

Tags: codeigniter, session, cookies, browser, error-handling

I'm using Codeigniter sessions for logging in users. For reasons that have always been mysterious to me, sometimes a user session gets destroyed and they have to log in again.

Because Codeigniter sessions are cookie based I assume I need to be looking at the browser to try to understand why the cookie got destroyed.

First of all, is that true? And if so, might someone suggest a method (php, js,  browser dev tools?) to log the errors that lead to each session getting destroyed?

Answer (score 0):

I would try checking the cookie timeout setting in **./application/config/config.php** and make sure this isn't something ridiculously low.

```
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
```

There are many other potential causes for this behavior, all of which depend on your environment.  For instance:

- If your code runs on multiple servers behind a load balancer not
  configured for "sticky sessions", then you will hit a new server
  (potentially) for every request, causing your session to be
  recreated.
- If your website utilizes multiple domains, your cookie will not be
  valid for all domains, only the one who created it.

But without knowing anything about your code or environment, I would recommend using firebug or chrome developer tools to check your cookie from your browser while checking what is being requested and responded in the network layer.

Comment: hi Brett thanks, to answer your questions my timeout is set to one month, it is a single server setup, and there is only one domain, so unfortunately these don't seem to be the problem, is there a logging in the browser or with php/codeigniter where I can track cookie states?